# OR condition validation in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

Having two select fields in template file

```
     <select id="ab" class="required-entry" name="abc" title="abc" >
      <option value="">-----</option>
        <option value="1">A </option>
         <option value="2">B </option>
       </select>
    <select id="dc" class="required-entry" name="dc" title="dc">
     <option value="">-----</option>
      <option value="3">C </option>
      <option value="4">D </option>
     </select>

     //<![CDATA[
   var brochureform = new VarienForm('form', true);

    //]]>
```

This code asks for two fileds madatory but I need to set only one is mandatory

Comment: Please use validate-one-required

Comment: I would suggest, you need to use custom validation and validate two field values, if both fields don't have value then you need to thought an error. Please check below link. https://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: @RajeshHothi where we use validate-one-required in class?